# How To Disable PanResponder on Child Component - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-0.46

Friend I will take oneView of Parents and Inside the View I take one TouchableOpacity. I Will Added panResponder on main View, And when touch of main view its working fine. But TouchableOpacity is not working, I want to remove panResponder on TouchableOpacity. So that TouchableOpacity is work.

**Code :**

```js
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,


      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The gesture has started. Show visual feedback so the user knows
        // what is happening!

        // gestureState.d{x,y} will be set to zero now

        // this.toggleModal()
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}

        // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
        // gestureState.d{x,y}
        console.log('onPanResponderMove');
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The user has released all touches while this view is the
        // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
        console.log('onPanResponderRelease');

        this.toggleModal()
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Another component has become the responder, so this gesture
        // should be cancelled

        console.log('onPanResponderTerminate');

      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Returns whether this component should block native components from becoming the JS
        // responder. Returns true by default. Is currently only supported on android.

        console.log('onShouldBlockNativeResponder');

        return true;
      },
    });
 }
```

**Pan added on Parents View :**

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
         <Image
          style={styles.button}
          source={require('./myButton.png')}
         />
       </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  },
```

The Button OnPress event isn't working when adding Pan on mainView.

Comment: Hope this link willl help you [Maintain Touchable Items with a Parent PanResponder](http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-maintain-touchable-items-with-a-parent-panresponder/)

Comment: good. but its work based on calculation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this line then inner `Touchables` will get the event.

when returning true, it will prevent child from become responder.

```js
  onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
```

From [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#capture-shouldset-handlers):

> So if a parent View wants to prevent the child from becoming responder
>   on a touch start, it should have a onStartShouldSetResponderCapture
>   handler which returns true.

Comment: I have also same problem on the FlatList. FlatList add in the parents view and the parents view have pan gesture. but when click on FlatList then parents view gesture always called.

Comment: `onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture` doesn't work well in iOS 14.0.1

Comment: doesnt work for me. onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture makes absolutely no difference